# Reference a keyvaul secret in a task from an environment variable in Azure devops pipelines

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know it sounds convoluted by bear with me:
I define a secret variable

```
- name: SECRET_VAR
  value: dev-secret
```

which I can use to get the secret from a keyvault by its name (dev-secret)

```
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      displayName: Load Key Vault Secrets
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
        KeyVaultName: $(KEYVAULT_NAME)
        SecretsFilter: $(SECRET_VAR)
        RunAsPreJob: true
```

I now want to use the secret in subsequent jobs with

```
    - task: Bash@3
      name : getToken
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken;isOutput=true]$(SECRET_VAR)"
```

and this obviously does not work as it evaluates to the dev-secret string but not the secret itself..
For sure I can use it with

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken;isOutput=true]$(dev-secret)"
```

But since I have multiple pipelines that have to get different secrets I need to make it dynamic.
how can I achieve this?

Comment: what does the `SECRET_VAR` var contains ? looks like a secret filter ? unclear if you are trying to re-use this variable or using a secret you fetch from kv ?

Comment: Isn´t it the first thing I put in? `SECRET_VAR` container the name of the keyvault secret, named dev-secret. And yes, I use it as a filter but as I stated below, I obliviously want the secret and not the name of the secret to be dynamically. hope this clarified things

Comment: @Bennimi, please check my reply below, you can change the value of variable `SECRET_VAR` in yaml, so that different keyvalut secret will be used in pipeline. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the **"SecretFilter" to '*'**, and prepare serveral secrets in azure keyvault. I have added two as my sample:

[image]

and below is my code, just apply to your own parameters and run. it will achieve your dynamic tokens.

```
parameters:
- name: serviceConnectionName
  type: string
  default: xxx
- name:  KeyVaultName
  type: string
  default: xxx

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: Load Key Vault Secrets
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    KeyVaultName: ${{ parameters.KeyVaultName }}
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: true 

- task: Bash@3
  name : getToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken;isOutput=true]$(dev-secret)"

- task: Bash@3
  name : getToken1
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken1;isOutput=true]$(dev-secret-1)"

- task: Bash@3
  name : echoToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $(getToken.myToken)
      echo $(getToken1.myToken1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's key valut secret, which will NOT mapped to environment. You can use `$(${{ variables.SECRET_VAR }})` in the logging command, and invoke in the next job.

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(${{ variables.SECRET_VAR }})"
```

My yaml below:

[image]

```
variables:
  - name: SECRET_VAR
    value: dev-secret
  - name: SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
    value: ARMConn3
  - name: KEYVAULT_NAME
    value: keyvalut4


jobs:
  - job: A
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        displayName: Load Key Vault Secrets
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
          KeyVaultName: $(KEYVAULT_NAME)
          SecretsFilter: $(SECRET_VAR)
          RunAsPreJob: true 

      - task: Bash@3
        name : getToken
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myToken;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(${{ variables.SECRET_VAR }})"

      - bash: echo $(getToken.myToken)  >> test1.txt

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/test1.txt'
          artifact: 'test1'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
        
  
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    variables:
      Tokenvalue: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['getToken.myToken'] ]
    steps:
    - bash: "echo $(Tokenvalue)"
      name: echovar
      
    - bash: echo $(Tokenvalue) >> test2.txt
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/test2.txt'
        artifact: 'test2'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Check in Job A:
test1.txt:

[image]

Check in Job B test2.txt：

[image]

Comment: hi wade, thanks, I think this goes in the right direction. I will test it later. Just a quick questions `SecretsFilter: $(TEST_VAR)` is a typo it should be `SECRET_VAR` or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Bennimi, yes, it's typo, i have corrected it in the sample yaml, thanks.

Comment: @Bennimi, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.